# Blender file and all its backups are corrupted. how can this be?

Tags: modeling, mesh

Hello all and thank you for any assistance! 
Im sorta new and using a imac 27" with a 3.5 GHz Quad-Core Intel Core i5 and have 32 gb of memory. I am not using any fancy UI but i have been using the "bool tool" add-on.
While working on a retopology of a mesh that I sculpted using the poly build tool , the blender program crashed when i was nearly done. (not the mac) Trying to reopen the file instantly crashes blender even though that saved file was saved 5 min before the 1st initial crash. I was even saving the file under a different name every time I saved it and that file crashes as well when opening. The backup "blend1" files with a time stamp that is 10 minutes older crash as well after renaming them with the proper blend extension. The sculpted mesh had about 500k of polygons and the retop layer maybe had 1000 at the most. I have also tried to append the object from the files and it crashes as well. Unfortunately i rebooted the computer hoping that would help before i knew of the existence of temp file that stored multiple backups from over the day.

How on earth can a blender file that was fine when saved and with a different name be corrupted? Am i missing something? This is the second time this has happened and I'm nearly to tears.

Comment: did you use multires modifier by any chance?

Comment: yeah i was using the shrink wrap and mirror modifier